# How to test Spotify ID?

Tags: php, header, embed, spotify

I wanna test if Spotify ID (converted from URI o URL) is OK. I did something similar with YouTube and it has been working. Unfortunatelly, this one not.

```
$headers = get_headers("https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/" . $value);
        if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

$value - SpotifyId

Comment: Did you try simple `var_dump($headers)`? It shows `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request` you need to debug why is that yourself.

Comment: @biesior Yes, I tried. I don't understand why it shows 400 since when I open this link by hand (in browser), it works

Comment: In general, it's an embed code. I can see that a valid response `200` is getting in the browser and REST client, but not in raw PHP like your `get_headers()` or `curl -I`. I assume that's some kind of prevention against fetching these data for other purposes than embedding. For sure you will have no such problems if you'll use a dedicated endpoint of Spotify's Web API i.e. [get-track](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-track/)

Comment: Note: The API will give you much more usable data like album covers, and a lot of detailed data instead of just checking if the track exists, anyway it requires getting an OAuth token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @biesior, I started using Laravel Spotify (from aerni). It hasn't everything, but there is enough functions for me. So I built search bar and there is displayed response from Spotify with everything: title, artist, preview, album etc. etc.